# How to show axis coordinate information on a bokeh plot?

Tags: graph, bokeh, axis, show

I currently have Hover implemented but it's a hassle with so much information to show.

That's why I need to make an axis for my bokeh figure() that shows at the end the information of my axes, Date and Price.

I have tried with crosshair but it only shows information of elements that are painted on the screen, can this be done with bokeh?

I attached a code to reproduce an example, I need the axis to report the time and price every time the mouse moves.
Thank you.

```
#Create the data to be plotted
time = np.arange(0,10,0.1)
price = np.sin(time)

#Create the figure with axes
p = figure(x_axis_label= 'time', y_axis_label= 'price',tools=["crosshair"])

#Add the line plot
p.line(time, price)

#Add the HoverTool
hover = HoverTool()
hover.tooltips = [
    ('Time', '@x'),
    ('Price', '@y'),
]

p.add_tools(hover)

#Display the graph
show(p)
```

info axis

[image: 1]

I am trying to look for an option to make an axis that provides information on bokeh plots, I hope someone can guide me if this is possible, my attempts have not been successful.

Comment: Can you please provide code for you example and describe why the HoverTool is not working? I think a well configurated Hovertool is perfect for your needs and maybe it just takes a few modifications. f `???` appears in the HoverTool, it because the source is not known, not because there is to much information to parse. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75492661/edit) your question and I will try to help.